# How to force React to render same component instance

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get React render props.children base on the screen size. This code does work but React recreate new component instance of props.children. Is there a way to force React to keep the same component instance so I won't loose its state?

I tried both useMemo() memo(). I tried using key prop. None of them works.

```
<Hidden mdUp>
  <Dialog open maxWidth="md" fullWidth>
    <DialogTitle>{props.header}</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>{props.children}</DialogContent>
    <DialogActions><Button onClick={props.onClose}>Close</Button></DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</Hidden>
<Hidden mdDown>
  <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>{props.header}</Typography>
  {props.children}
</Hidden>
```

Comment: you are doing conditional rendering so your children from one place will unmount and it will mount from another place. I am not sure it is possible with setup you have.

Comment: BTW what is Hiden component?

Comment: @eramit2010 Hidden is a component from Material-UI package. Like bootstrap feature. It show or hide its children base on screen size.
In the beginning I tought that if I have the main content in parent component and pass it in to this component as children. The component instance of main content would be kept. But It just recreate another one

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and return `true`? It will render your component either your props changed or not.

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate it's like the indicator of whether it should be re-render....but the problem is not really that. I have a component that I want to show in dialog when it's small screen or just render it somewhere in the page. But when the screen resize I am hoping the component to just unmount from dialog and mount to other place without recreating a whole new instance and loose all the states in the component

Comment: Interesting.. Have you heard about [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)? It looks like it fits into your description.